# How can I return a datareader when using Entity Framework 4?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-4.1

I want to define a database query using LINQ and my EntityFramework context but I don't want entities returned; I want a datareader!

How can I do this? This is for exporting rows to a CSV.

Cheers, Ian.

Comment: Why not just get the objects and serialize those to CSV?

Comment: I don't know how many objects there will be so a datareader stops the server's memory filling up.

Comment: From looking around a bit, you may not be able to get to it easily, there is an [ExecuteDbDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executedbdatareader(v=VS.90).aspx) method, but it's protected so you probably shouldn't be trying to get a hold of it.  If this isn't done very often and/or if the query isn't overly expensive, you could try paging the results of your query to ensure that you don't have too many objects in memory at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is around EF 4, but for anyone else with EF 6 or higher you can use the AsStreaming() extension method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn237204(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: For anyone who is like me and has no idea what AsStreaming() does, here is the only passing reference I was able to find for it: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design%20Meeting%20Notes%20-%20December%206%2C%202012. There seems to be no other documentation anywhere.

Comment: This method is now obsolete and calling it has no effect because LINQ queries are streaming by default. I am guessing that is only for EF6, though. You should still use Ladislav's answer for EF4.

Answer (score 22):

If you need this you are more probably doing something unexpected. Simple iteration through materialized result of the query should be what you need - that is ORM way. If you don't like it use `SqlCommand` directly.

DbContext API is simplified and because of that it doesn't contain many features available in ObjectContext API. Accessing data reader is one of them. You can try to convert `DbContext` to `ObjectContext` and use the more complex API:

```
ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
using (var connection = objContext.Connection as EntityConnection)
{
    // Create Entity SQL command querying conceptual model hidden behind your code-first mapping
    EntityCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT VALUE entity FROM ContextName.DbSetName AS entity";
    connection.Open();
    using (EntityDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But pure ADO.NET way is much easier and faster because the former example still uses mapping of query to SQL query:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM DbSetName";
    connection.Open();
    using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: "If you need this you are more probably doing something unexpected." I don't think there's anything particularly strange about requesting a large number of objects for export or to generate emails. The ORM could still materialize objects but stream them from the database in a pure data reader kind of way. LLBLGen allows one to get hold of a data reader. http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/2.6/Using%20the%20generated%20code/SelfServicing/gencode_datareadersprojections.htm