# Is there a way to iterate through an EF6 Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a web form with around 50 fields that is used for crud operations on an Oracle DB, I am using EF6.
Currently, I accomplish this like so:

```
private GENERIC_FTP_SEND GetFields()
{
    GENERIC_FTP_SEND ftpPartner = new GENERIC_FTP_SEND();

    //Contact Info
    ftpPartner.FTP_LOOKUP_ID = FTP_LOOKUP_IDTB.Text;
    ftpPartner.PARTNER_NAME = PARTNER_NAMETB.Text;
    ftpPartner.REMEDY_QUEUE = REMEDY_QUEUETB.Text;
    ftpPartner.PRIORITY = PRIORITYBtns.SelectedValue;
    ftpPartner.CONTACT_EMAIL = CONTACT_EMAILTB.Text;
    ftpPartner.CONTACT_NAME = CONTACT_NAMETB.Text;
    ftpPartner.CONTACT_PHONE = CONTACT_PHONETB.Text;
    ...
}
```

where GENERIC_FTP_SEND is the name of the virtual DbSet in my Model.context.cs.

This works fine but is not reusable in the least. What I would like to accomplish is to have some code that allows me to iterate through the attributes of ftpPartner and compare them to the field id for a match. Something like this:

```
var n =0;
foreach (Control cntrl in ControlList){
    if(cntrl.ID == ftpPartner[n]){
         ftpPartner[n] = cntrl.Text;
    }
    n++;
}
```

In case you need/want to see it here is my Model.context.cs

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext{

public Entities(): base("name=Entities")
{
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
}

public virtual DbSet<GENERIC_FTP_SEND> GENERIC_FTP_SEND { get; set; }

}
```

I saw the question here but I am not sure how to implement that in my case.
[Entity Framework 6: is there a way to iterate through a table without holding each row in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795406/entity-framework-6-is-there-a-way-to-iterate-through-a-table-without-holding-ea)

Comment: With Reflection maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151888/c-sharp-iterate-through-class-properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with reflection:

```
var type = typeof(GENERIC_FTP_SEND);
foreach (Control cntrl in ControlList){
    Object value = null;


    if (cntrl is TextBox){
         value = (cntrl as TextBox).Text;
    } else if (cntrl is GroupBox){
         value = (cntrl as GroupBox).SelectedValue;
    } //etc ...



    PropertyInfo pInfo = type.GetProperty(cntrl.ID);
    if (pInfo != null && value != null){
        pInfo.SetValue(ftpPartner, value, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: The Tag (Or maybe name) property would be a good place to store the field name.  With this in mind, it'd be pretty trivial to build the form this is shown on from the data type as well.

Comment: Works great and does exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure what you mean about being trivial.

Comment: Pretty much the opposite of the above.  Instead of pulling the values out of the Controls collection, you put them into the controls collection in the constructor.  Make a label with the property name, and a data entry control with the corresponding data type for each property.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Entity Framework context object as well to accomplish the same if you know you are going to insert.

```
var x = new GENERIC_FTP_SEND();

//  Add it to your context immediately
ctx.GENERIC_FTP_SEND.Add(x);

//  Then something along these lines 
foreach (Control cntrl in ControlList)
{
    ctx.Entry(x).Property(cntrl.Name).CurrentValue = ctrl.Text;
}
```

Comment: This looks really simple but I will also need to work with existing data.

Comment: Existing data can be retrieved using a linq query instead of `new`. Works the same way